# Abstracting an id attribute in C# or Java

Tags: c#, java

I am designing an API. Here are some example methods from an interface:

```
Entry findEntry(int processId);
Entry findEntry(int processId, Filter filter);
```

where `processId` refers to some unique identifying information. However I don't really know what the type of `processId` is yet.

How can I abstract away an element like `id` of something?

The best I could come up with is creating a dummy interface:

```
Entry findEntry(ProcessId id);
Entry findEntry(ProcessId, Filter filter);
```

However, I worry that with the above approach I may force the client of the API to operate on too high an abstraction level. For example, the equality of process id's will no longer work (whereas if they used int's - it would).

*Clarification*: I failed to clarify that I am writing only the interfaces (contracts), to be implemented later, possibly by a different team. That is why I cannot enforce certain things like equals method.

Comment: And how do You want this to work in C# and Java?

Comment: I think a process ID may be a string or an int.Looking at your interface it won't be a complex type

Comment: `For example, the equality of process id's will no longer work` Define a compare method?

Comment: Equality is determined by the `equals()` method of the class in Java, which can be overridden if you want to test for equality. In C# I have no idea how this works, but probably quite similarly. It would help if you narrowed your question down to a single language.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop, but I posed the question in multiple language to avoid very language specific answers. IMO this is more of a theoretical question, the solution to which  should work in most statically typed languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics is your friend here

on the method itself if appropriate

```
Entry findEntry<TKey>(TKey processId);
```

or possible the class

```
public class EntryFinder<TKey>
{
  public Entry findEntry(TKey processId)
  {
     // Implementation
  }
}
```

**Edit**: If you're defining the interface, you can also define this there and leave it to the implemntors of the interface to figure out what type they want to use to identify an Entry.

```
public interface IEntryFinder<TKey>
{
  Entry findEntry(TKey processId);
}
```

Usage:

```
// Foo's are looked up by integer
public class FooEntryFinder : IEntryFinder<int>
{
  public Entry findEntry(int processId)
  {
     // Implementation
  }
}
// Baa's are looked up by string
public class BaaEntryFinder : IEntryFinder<string>
{
  public Entry findEntry(string processId)
  {
     // Implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use generics instead of inheritance? There seems to be absolutely no reason or justification for it.

Comment: @biziclop - Did I say this was the *only* solution? Feel free to post another answer with another solution.

Comment: It just looks overly complicated and unnecessary.

Comment: @biziclop - WTF?! What is overcomplicated by defining one generic type and using it to specify the "type of key (TKey) to use when finding an entry".

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting idea. However, if I have different interfaces that all make use of this `TKey` there is really no way of enforcing it. I'll have to give it a go.

Comment: @drozzy You can (in C# at least) specify the generic type on the interface and leave it to implementors later on to define the concrete type to use... i'll update my answer with this idea.

Comment: @Jamiec In C# it may not be, in Java it definitely is. (Goes back to my original comment that the question should be narrowed down to one language only.)

Comment: It's not that complicated in Java either and is used quite a bit with Hibernate - look up GenericDaoHibernate for examples that need to load by a String or Long entity identifier etc.

Comment: Thanks @BedwyrHumphreys, that GenericDoaHibernate class is excellent! I knew there would be an example of something similar to this.